# Match a key in both MySQL tables and return one with the max value

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables in MySQL:

Table 1 called **Alpha**

```
+-------------------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+---------------+
| mID                     | mtype         | source        | state           | tstamp        |
+-------------------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+---------------+
| 1111A-1111A-1111A-1111A | ON            | 12345         | NORMAL          | 1590000000000 |
| 1111A-1111A-3333A-3333A | ON            | 12345         | NORMAL          | 1590000020000 |
| 1111A-1111A-4444A-4444A | ON            | 12345         | NORMAL          | 1590000031000 |
| 1111A-1111A-5555A-5555A | ON            | 23456         | NORMAL          | 1590000040000 |
| 1111A-1111A-5555A-5555A | ON            | 23456         | NORMAL          | 1590000045000 |
| 1111A-1111A-6666A-6666A | ON            | 23456         | NORMAL          | 1590000050000 |
| 1111A-1111A-6666A-6666A | ON            | 23456         | NORMAL          | 1590000055000 |
| 1111A-1111A-7777A-7777A | ON            | 23456         | NORMAL          | 1590000061000 |
+-------------------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

Table 2 called **Bravo**

```
+-------------------------+-----------------+---------------+
| mID                     | mtype           | tstamp        |
+-------------------------+-----------------+---------------+
| 1111A-1111A-2222A-2222A | OFF             | 1590000010000 |
| 1111A-1111A-3333A-3333A | OFF             | 1590000021000 |
| 1111A-1111A-4444A-4444A | OFF             | 1590000030000 |
| 1111A-1111A-5555A-5555A | OFF             | 1590000041000 |
| 1111A-1111A-6666A-6666A | OFF             | 1590000051000 |
| 1111A-1111A-6666A-6666A | OFF             | 1590000056000 |
| 1111A-1111A-7777A-7777A | OFF             | 1590000060000 |
| 1111A-1111A-7777A-7777A | OFF             | 1590000065000 |
+-------------------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

I want to write a MYSQL query to join these two tables in the following way:

Match table (Alpha) with table (Bravo) and if:

- Only 1 mID exist in either table, just return it.
- If both table has same mID, then return the one with the maximum tstamp value and its type.

So the expected result would be:

```
+-------------------------+-----------------+---------------+
| mID                     | mtype           | tstamp        |
+-------------------------+-----------------+---------------+
| 1111A-1111A-1111A-1111A | ON              | 1590000000000 |
| 1111A-1111A-2222A-2222A | OFF             | 1590000010000 |
| 1111A-1111A-3333A-3333A | OFF             | 1590000021000 |
| 1111A-1111A-4444A-4444A | ON              | 1590000031000 |
| 1111A-1111A-5555A-5555A | ON              | 1590000045000 |
| 1111A-1111A-6666A-6666A | OFF             | 1590000056000 |
| 1111A-1111A-7777A-7777A | OFF             | 1590000065000 |
+-------------------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

I'm not great with mySQL, but I just managed to do some joins but can't get it working as expected!

Comment: Please show what you currently have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL have no FULL JOIN so you must emulate it (collect all `mID` values from both tables):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT mID FROM Alpha
              UNION
              SELECT mID FROM Bravo )
SELECT mID, GREATEST(COALESCE(Alpha.tstamp, 0), COALESCE(Bravo.tstamp, 0)) AS tstamp
FROM cte 
LEFT JOIN Alpha USING (mID)
LEFT JOIN Bravo USING (mID)
```

COALESCE needed because GREATEST does not like NULL in arguments.

Alternatively you may use

```
CASE WHEN Alpha.tstamp IS NULL THEN Bravo.tstamp
     WHEN Bravo.tstamp IS NULL THEN Alpha.tstamp
     ELSE GREATEST(Alpha.tstamp, Bravo.tstamp)
     END AS tstamp
```

It will do the same.

---

Another solution:

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT mID, tstamp FROM Alpha
              UNION ALL
              SELECT mID, tstamp FROM Bravo )
SELECT mID, MAX(tstamp) tstamp
FROM cte
GROUP BY mID;
```

This will work even if `mID` is not defined as UNIQUE.

---

> only thing is when I add another column "mType" too, it sometimes give me the wrong value. For e.g. for 3,6,7 it should be value OFF, but it has value ON? – Saffik

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT mID, tstamp, mType FROM Alpha
          UNION ALL
          SELECT mID, tstamp, mType FROM Bravo ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT mID, tstamp, mType, 
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mID ORDER BY tstamp DESC) rn
          FROM cte1 )
SELECT mID, tstamp, mType
FROM cte2 
WHERE rn = 1;
```

What record must be returned if there exists 2 records with the same `mID`, `tstamp` and different `mType` - decide by yourself.

Comment: I think your first query  partly works... still returns two values for some mIDs

Comment: @Saffik Another variant added.

Comment: Great, just tried your (Another solution:) It works as expected, only thing is when I add another column "mType" too, it sometimes give me the wrong value. For e.g. for 3,6,7 it should be value OFF, but it has value ON? - Any idea? :)

Comment: @Saffik Was it really so difficult to post THE ENTIRE TASK at once? wait...

Comment: You are a MySQL God. Works as expected!